# how to print html page with image in Qprinter pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine, qprinter

i have generated a report for my program using html code but it doesn't show image in Qprinter.

```
def run(self):
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    view.setHtml("""<img src="header.jpeg" alt="logo" width="280" height="100">""")
    printer = QPrinter()
    printer.setPaperSize(QtCore.QSizeF(80 ,297), QPrinter.Millimeter)
    try :
        r = QPrintDialog(printer)
        if r.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted:
            view.page().print(printer, self.print_completed)
    except Exception as e :
        print(e)
```

html code that i want to print .
the header.jpeg in same directory  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt Webengine executes the tasks asynchronously as printing, and since view and printer are local variables they will be eliminated when the synchro function is finished. The solution is to keep those objects even when you finish running.

Not necessary to use QWebEngineView since you will not show anything, just QWebEnginePage.

On the other hand the docs states that external resources such as images are loaded based on the URL that is passed second parameter. So the solution is to pass a url using the current directory as a basis.

```
import os
# ...
def run(self):
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    self._page = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage()
    self._page.setHtml('''
    ... <img src="header.jpeg" alt="logo" width="280" height="100"> ...
    ''', QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(current_dir, "index.html")))
    self._printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
    self._printer.setPaperSize(QtCore.QSizeF(80 ,297), QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.Millimeter)
    r = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog(self._printer)
    if r.exec_() == QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog.Accepted:
        self._page.print(self._printer, self.print_completed)
```

Comment: i do it  as you say but still image not showing in print .

Comment: @Hackerpoint image? What image do you mean? Do you get the pdf? In your HTML there is no image, you could improve your [mcve]

Comment: my html code has <img src="header.jpeg" alt="logo" width="280" height="100"> when i open my html file i fount image correct but when print give me alt word but not showing the image

Comment: @Hackerpoint Where is the image? Are you on the side of your .py ?, please add that code to your question

Comment: @Hackerpoint When you say: *when i open my html* with what do you open it? With google-chrome, firefox or what?

Comment: @Hackerpoint Do you read the HTML from an .html file or do you create it with code?

Comment: yes when i open with any browser it's open and picture are located correct but when i print it via a printer dose't show image , sorry   , i am weak in English