# print a file with certain extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qprinter

I'd like to print a file selected with a file picker (or somehow) with
certain extension, so that `PyQt` or printer will automatically recognize
the format (e.g. `pdf`, `ms word`, `excel`, `txt`, `html`, `jpg` etc.)

So far, I have found [here](https://youtu.be/k8r34cRasxM?list=PL1FgJUcJJ03uO70zDLDF3oaTu6s2QLOPa) how to print the content
of the TextEdit, but I'd like to print files with various formats.

Is it possible with `PyQt5` or should I search elsewhere?

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Because network printers are not different from local printer (as long as they are available to the underlying system printing system). On the other hand, printing with the formats you list might differ **a lot** from format to format, and specific/proprietary formats require use of external libraries.

Comment: @musicamante OK, it will be sufficient to print txt and pdf formats, and if I would need more formats, I would ask another question. Now, I understand (as you have written), that I will probably need to use libraries for various formats.

Comment: It would be sufficient to select the file from the file picker and as an action on button click to print it as pdf or txt (according to file extension).

Comment: @xralf If your question has changed then you should edit the title and content of your question

Comment: @xralf You cannot and should not ask 2 such different questions in a post: printer network and print different formats since they are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing a plain text document does not require a *viewer*, since the [`print_()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#print) function actually calls the internal QDocument's [`print_()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#print) function:

```
filePath, filter = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '', 'Text (*.txt)')
if not filePath:
    return
doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
try:
    with open(filePath, 'r') as txtFile:
        doc.setPlainText(txtFile.read())
    printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.HighResolution)
    if not QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog(printer, self).exec_():
        return
    doc.print_(printer)
except Exception as e:
    print('Error trying to print: {}'.format(e))
```

You might want to add some functionalities to set the page size, document margins, font sizes etc, before actually printing (just read the QTextDocument docs), I'll leave that to you.

---

Printing from html files is almost similar, but you'll need to use the [QWebEnginePage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html) class from QtWebEngineWidgets. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54716438).
Do *not* use `QTextDocument.setHtml()`, as Qt has limited support for html tags.

The same is valid for PDF files too, the difference is that the file has to be loaded through [`setUrl()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#url-prop) and the [QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#WebAttribute-enum) setting has to be enabled through [`page.settings().setAttribute(setting, bool)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#setAttribute) in case it's not.
Read the documentation about [PDF File Viewing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#pdf-file-viewing).

---

Printing images could be done through two approaches.

The first and simpler, is to create a temporary html file that embeds the image and load to a webengine page as above (you could add controls for zoom/scaling).

Alternatively, you could directly print using QPainter, but you'll have to relate to the printer resolution and image size, so you'd probably want to have a preview dialog before actually printing the image, otherwise it might be too small (or too big).

While more complex than a plain `<html><img src=""></html>`, this allows a better control on the positioning and sizing of the image[s].

```
class ImagePrintPreview(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, printer, pixmap):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.printer = printer
        self.pixmap = pixmap

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        self.viewer = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.viewer, 0, 0, 1, 2)

        self.resoCombo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.resoCombo, 1, 0)

        self.zoom = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(minimum=50, maximum=200, suffix='%')
        self.zoom.setValue(100)
        self.zoom.setAccelerated(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.zoom, 1, 1)
        self.zoom.valueChanged.connect(self.updatePreview)

        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        default = printer.resolution()
        self.resoCombo.addItem(str(default), default)
        for dpi in (150, 300, 600, 1200):
            if dpi == default:
                continue
            self.resoCombo.addItem(str(dpi), dpi)
        self.resoCombo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updatePreview)

        self.updatePreview()

    def updatePreview(self):
        # create a preview to show how the image will be printed
        self.printer.setResolution(self.resoCombo.currentData())
        paperRect = self.printer.paperRect(self.printer.DevicePixel)
        printRect = self.printer.pageRect(self.printer.DevicePixel)

        # a temporary pixmap that will use the printer's page size
        # note that page/paper are QRectF, they have a QSizeF which has to
        # be converted to a QSize
        pm = QtGui.QPixmap(paperRect.size().toSize())
        # new pixmap have allocated memory for their contents, which usually
        # result in some random pixels, just fill it with white
        pm.fill(QtCore.Qt.white)
        # start a qpainter on the pixmap
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(pm)
        # scale the pixmap to the wanted zoom value
        zoom = self.zoom.value() * .01
        scaled = self.pixmap.scaledToWidth(int(self.pixmap.width() * zoom), QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        # paint the pixmap aligned to the printing margins
        qp.drawPixmap(printRect.topLeft(), scaled)

        # other possible alternatives:

        # Center the image:
        #   qp.translate(printRect.center())
        #   delta = QtCore.QPointF(scaled.rect().center())
        #   qp.drawPixmap(-delta, scaled)

        # To also rotate 90° clockwise, add this to the above:
        #   qp.rotate(90)
        # *after* qp.translate() and before qp.drawPixmap()


        # when painting to a non QWidget device, you always have to end the
        # painter before being able to use it
        qp.end()
        # scale the temporary pixmap to a fixed width
        self.viewer.setPixmap(pm.scaledToWidth(300, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))

    def exec_(self):
        if super().exec_():
            self.printer.setResolution(self.resoCombo.currentData())
            # do the same as above, but paint directly on the printer device
            printRect = self.printer.pageRect(self.printer.DevicePixel)
            qp = QtGui.QPainter(self.printer)
            zoom = self.zoom.value() * .01
            scaled = self.pixmap.scaledToWidth(int(self.pixmap.width() * zoom), QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            qp.drawPixmap(printRect.topLeft(), scaled)
            # as above, that's important!
            qp.end()


class ImagePrinter(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        selBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open image')
        layout.addWidget(selBtn)
        selBtn.clicked.connect(self.selectFile)

    def selectFile(self):
        filePath, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/tmp', 'Images (*.jpg *.png)')
        if not filePath:
            return
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(filePath)
        if pixmap.isNull():
            return

        printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.HighResolution)
        if QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog(printer, self).exec_():
            ImagePrintPreview(self, printer, pixmap).exec_()
```

Note that I couldn't test this under windows, so it might be necessary to change things related to the resolution (possibly by using `printer.supportedResolutions()`).

---

As already explained in the comments, printing to other (and possibly proprietary) formats requires external modules.

Comment: Could you please show the PDF file yet? The documentation is for C++. If it's clear to you (of course). Thank you

Comment: And there is one drawback yet. I cannot choose the printer, from available printers on the network.

Comment: @xralf What do you mean by "show the PDF file"? About the network printing, unfortunately I cannot help you, as I'm on Linux; if you're on Windows and are referring to printers shared along the network (the "active directory"), I *believe* that they are not listed by default, unless they *are* the default printer. Try creating a new printer and manually set the printer name using the full `\\` path.

Comment: I mean, show printing the PDF file, now it's printing text document only (txt).

Comment: And yet, could you please post complete code in image printing section. I'm struggling with the import statements.

Comment: @xralf I never had the opportunity to actually test the PDF printing, but it should work in the same way the html works (as long as you've enabled the plugins): set the url to the file path. About the import, I just imported the base submodules of PyQt5 that already are in the prefixes of the classes used in the example: QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets and QtPrintSupport.